# change page Indicator Image [SMPageControl] / EAIntroView in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm trying to change the indicator image , following the example in [EAIntroView](https://github.com/ealeksandrov/EAIntroView/blob/master/Example/Source/ViewController.m)

here is the objective-c code from EAIntroView

```
SMPageControl *pageControl = [[SMPageControl alloc] init];
pageControl.pageIndicatorImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pageDot"];
pageControl.currentPageIndicatorImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"selectedPageDot"];
[pageControl sizeToFit];
intro.pageControl = (UIPageControl *)pageControl;
intro.pageControlY = 130.f;
```

and here is the swift code I'm trying to implement

```
    // SMPageControl
    pageControl = SMPageControl()
    pageControl.pageIndicatorImage = UIImage(named: "pageDot")
    pageControl.currentPageIndicatorImage = UIImage(named: "selectedPageDot")
  pageControl.sizeToFit()
  pageControl.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    intro.pageControl = pageControl as? UIPageControl
```

swift code has a warning here

```
        intro.pageControl = pageControl as? UIPageControl
```

the warning is :

```
Cast from 'SMPageControl!' to unrelated type 'UIPageControl' always fails
```

any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see from [the source code of SMPageControl](https://github.com/Spaceman-Labs/SMPageControl/blob/master/SMPageControl.h) that it isn't a subclass of `UIPageControl`. Which means the error is expected: `UIPageControl` is a completely unrelated type, to which the value cannot be cast.

The Objective-C you pointed to might work, but it's bad and wrong: inline cast to `UIPageControl` achieves nothing here and can cause internal inconsistencies.

This is exactly the kind of sloppiness that Swift compiler is designed to prevent, and it's doing its job well.

Your best bet is to forgo using this library in Swift code.

Answer (score 4):

For changing page Indicator Image [SMPageControl] / EAIntroView in swift I have created custom class of **UIPageControl** like below:

```
import UIKit 
class CustomPageControl: UIPageControl {

let activePage: UIImage = UIImage(named: "icon-selected-dot")!
let inActivePage: UIImage = UIImage(named: "icon-dot")!

override var numberOfPages: Int {
    didSet {
        updateDots()
    }
}

override var currentPage: Int {
    didSet {
        updateDots()
    }
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.clear
    self.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.clear
    self.clipsToBounds = false
}

func updateDots() {
    var i = 0
    for view in self.subviews {
        var imageView = self.imageView(forSubview: view)
        if imageView == nil {
            if i == self.currentPage {
                imageView = UIImageView(image: activePage)
            } else {
                imageView = UIImageView(image: inActivePage)
            }
            imageView!.center = view.center
            view.addSubview(imageView!)
            view.clipsToBounds = false
        }
        if i == self.currentPage {
            imageView!.alpha = 1.0
            imageView?.image = activePage
        } else {
            imageView!.alpha = 0.5
            imageView?.image = inActivePage
        }
        i += 1
    }
}

fileprivate func imageView(forSubview view: UIView) -> UIImageView? {
    var dot: UIImageView?
    if let dotImageView = view as? UIImageView {
        dot = dotImageView
    } else {
        for foundView in view.subviews {
            if let imageView = foundView as? UIImageView {
                dot = imageView
                break
            }
        }
    }
    return dot
}
}
```

then in your class just add these lines and you can use custom images for dot

```
//Custom page Control
    let pageControl = CustomPageControl()
    pageControl.updateDots()
    intro.pageControl = pageControl
```

Hope it will work for you! @ynamao